# Gradually change color of UIImage from RGB to Grayscale

Tags: swift, uiimage, swift2, rgb, grayscale

I have an `UIImage` in a `UIScrollView` which can be scrolled from one end to the other. Lets say left is 0.0% and right is 100.0%.

The `UIImage` is a colored Image in the RGB range which I want to gradually change to a gray scale depending on the scroll position.

I researched this but couldn't find any answer to gradually changing it. Obviously rendering it in ray scale at once is possible.

Is there a possibility to do this in Swift?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Duncan for the technically correct answer. This does work but unfortunately it hast lag when scrolling. This is why I went with the Joerns solution to place two images above each other (one colored and one in grayscale) and change the alpha values accordingly.
If anyone wants the code to Duncans suggestion here you go:

```
if let image = image
{
    let icon = CIImage(CGImage: image)

    if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
    {
        filter.setValue(icon, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter.setValue(0.0, forKey: kCIInputSaturationKey)

        if let ciImage = filter.outputImage
        {
            let context = CIContext(options:nil)
            let cgImage = context.createCGImage(ciImage, fromRect: ciImage.extent)

            imageView.image = UIImage(CIImage: cgImage)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean about having it change based on scroll position? Do you want the saturation to change gradually from left to right on your image, or do you want the entire visible part of the image to use a single saturation value that changes depending on the scroll position? My answer assumed you wanted a left-to-right change in saturation. Simon's answer would let you change the saturation on the whole current visible area based on scroll position.

Comment: @DuncanC See my edit above

Comment: @freshking you can create a context using CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray and draw the image on it. That would be 10x faster than filter. In my machinee 0.07121700048446655 against 0.6915000081062317 using CIColorControls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to implement a CoreImage filter on the fly but the performance was horrible. So I ended up having one image with colors and one image with grayscales. Both image views are stacked and their alphas is changed according to the scroll position. The result is a nice and smooth transition from color to grayscale when you scroll:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    let cgImage = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")!.CGImage!
    let colorImage = UIImageView()
    let grayscaleImage = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let image = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")!
        colorImage.image = image
        scrollView.addSubview(colorImage)

        let beginImage = CIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")!
        filter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        filter.setValue(0, forKey: kCIInputSaturationKey)
        grayscaleImage.image = UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage!)
        scrollView.addSubview(grayscaleImage)

        scrollView.contentSize = image.size
        colorImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)
        grayscaleImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let percentage = scrollView.contentOffset.x / (scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.bounds.size.width)
        colorImage.alpha = percentage
        grayscaleImage.alpha = 1 - percentage
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. So you used a hybrid of mine and Simon's solutions. BTW, did you test on a device, or on the simulator? I found that CI filters perform much better on the device.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. When I tested it in the Simulator performance was so bad, that I did not even bother to test it on a device. Still I found out that the problem was not in the filter but in the fact that you had to change the image each time you change the filter. That is not performant when you use large images. Which I suppose is the case here.

Comment: BTW, it's a pleasure to offer a solution and have somebody go implement it rather than asking the answerer to write the code.

Comment: Actually I hadn't seen you answers when I implemented this. So it's more a case of "great minds think alike" ;-)

Comment: Hi, great stuff!

I've applied Core Image filters in real time by doing the processing in a background thread. I've been able to apply them to video feeds, so that might be worth considering if you ever revisit this.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Probably the cleanest way to do this is to set up a Core Image filter that dials back the color saturation of the image. I'm not quite sure what you mean about changing to gray scale "depending on the scroll position". Are you saying that you want your image to be fully saturated on the left, say, and then fully grayscale on the right, with a gradual transition from color to B&W?

To get that effect I'd probably do the following:

Use a Core image filter to create a version of the image that was grayscale.
Place the color image on the bottom with the B&W image on top. Then create a linear gradient and apply that to the top image's mask layer. The end effect would be that the top B&W image would fully cover the color image where it was opaque, and fully expose the color image where it was transparent, and you'd see a blend of the 2 where the B&W image was partly transparent.

You could probably also get the same effect by stacking multiple Core Image filters, but I haven't actually done that before, just read about it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a CoreImage `CIColorControls` filter which has a saturation parameter. Simply link the saturation value to the normalised scroll position and, voila, you have the effect you're looking for.

Simon